# Webpack Angular Code Splitting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I currently have a project set up like this: [image] Since angular material is a big download for my project,a white screen stays loading for about 45s. I am trying to do some code splitting to make my application load faster but I am getting errors. Code splitting does not seem to work for me.

**core/app.module.js**

```
'use strict';

require.ensure([], function (require) {

    require('angular/angular.min');
    require('angular-aria/angular-aria.min');
    require('angular-animate/angular-animate.min');
    require('angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min');

}, 'common');

var page1Module = require('./../page1/page1.module');
var page2Module = require('./../page2/page2.module');
var appRunBlock = require('./app.run');
var appConfig = require('./app.config');

var moduleName = 'app';

var app = angular.module(moduleName, [
        'ui.router',
        page1Module,
        page2Module
    ])
    .config(appConfig)
    .run(appRunBlock);

module.exports = moduleName;
```

**page1/page1.module.js**

```
'use strict';

require.ensure([], function (require) {

    require('angular-material/modules/js/core/core.min.js');
    require('angular-material/modules/js/core/core.min.css');
    require('angular-material/modules/js/core/default-theme.js');
    require('angular-material/modules/js/button/button.min.js');
    require('angular-material/modules/js/button/button.min.css');

}, 'page1');

var page1Route = require('./page1.route');
var page1Controller = require('./page1.controller');

var moduleName = 'app.page1';

angular.module(moduleName, [
        'material.components.button'
    ])
    .config(page1Route)
    .controller('Page1Controller', page1Controller);

module.exports = moduleName;
```

**page2/page2.module.js**

```
'use strict';

require.ensure([], function (require) {

    require('angular-material/modules/js/core/core.min.js');
    require.include('angular-material/modules/js/core/core.min.css');
    require.include('angular-material/modules/js/core/default-theme.js');
    require('angular-material/modules/js/toolbar/toolbar.min.js');
    require('angular-material/modules/js/toolbar/toolbar.min.css');
    require('angular-material/modules/js/content/content.min.js');
    require('angular-material/modules/js/content/content.min.css');
    require('angular-material/modules/js/input/input.min.js');
    require('angular-material/modules/js/input/input.min.css');

}, 'page2');

var page2Route = require('./page2.route');
var page2Controller = require('./page2.controller');

var moduleName = 'app.page2';

angular.module(moduleName, [
        'material.components.toolbar',
        'material.components.content',
        'material.components.input'
    ])
    .config(page2Route)
    .controller('Page2Controller', page2Controller);

module.exports = moduleName;
```

I have this **webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

var webpack_config = {
    context: path.join(__dirname + '/app'),
    entry: {
        app: './core/app.module.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname + '/release'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: '/js/[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '/js/[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: 'node_modules',
                loader: 'style!css'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: 'node_modules',
                loader: 'style!css!sass'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: 'node_modules',
                loader: 'ngtemplate?relativeTo=' + (path.join(__dirname, './app')) + '/!html?' +
                JSON.stringify({attrs: ['img:src', 'img:ng-src', 'md-icon:md-svg-src']})
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from: './index.html', to: './index.html'}
        ])
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve('./release')
    },
    watch: true
};

module.exports = webpack_config;
```

I have tried to use require.include inside require.ensure to load my files as I need them and it does not work. I have put my libs path in the require.ensure([]) array and it does not work.

The only time it works if I put a second entry in webpack.config.js and put all my libs in a common chunk named 'vendor' or if I use require() not require.ensure().

Loading my angular material lib is about 1.5 MB and it takes about 30s or 1m.  When the app load it has a white screen until all libs load.  That is the reason I need to code split. I am using webpack-dev-server and it throws the following errors [image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like I needed to use ocLazyLoading for loading modules dynamically.  I also learned that you need to know the place and also the trigger when you want to load your modules, template or lib.  In my case I needed to load my modules with ocLazyLoading on the route.